# Enumerating sliced array using original indices

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I need to slice an array and enumerate the values but I also need the reference to the original index because I'm doing an async operation that needs to be mapped back to the original index in the original array when complete.

```
const array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge'];
const slicedArray = array.slice(0, 3).map((v, i) => ({ v, i }));
// Returns: [{ "v": "foo", "i": 0 }, { "v": "bar", "i": 1 }, { "v": "baz", "i": 2 }]
// Required: [{ "v": "foo", "i": 0 }, { "v": "bar", "i": 1 }, { "v": "baz", "i": 2 }]
const slicedArray2 = array.slice(3, 6).map((v, i) => ({ v, i }));
// Returns: [{ "v": "qux", "i": 0 }, { "v": "quux", "i": 1 }, { "v": "corge", "i": 2 }]
// Required: [{ "v": "qux", "i": 3 }, { "v": "quux", "i": 4 }, { "v": "corge", "i": 5 }]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: First map *then* slice, if you want the original indexes. Or add an offset to the index.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to just wait for a bunch of promises to resolve in parallel? For this, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Yes, I'm using `Promise.allSettled` but I wouldn't know the original index because slice always resets it right? @VLAZ Not ideal, the original array is quite large.

Comment: Yes, slice "resets" the index, since it just makes a new array. However, `Promise.allSettled()` wouldn't alter the order of items. If you do `Promise.allSettled(foo(arr.slice(0, 3)), foo(arr.slice(3, 6)))` you'd get back two arrays where the first one corrsponds to indexes 0-2, the second one to indexes 3-5. It shouldn't be hard to match the result to the original. You can grab all results and `.concat()` them into an array that will match the original (or can overwrite it, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in the slice always have indexes that are exactly `startIndex` less than in the original array:

```
slice(0, 3) -> [0, 1, 2] -> [0 - 0, 1 - 0, 2 - 0]
slice(3, 6) -> [0, 1, 2] -> [3 - 3, 4 - 3, 5 - 3]
slice(n, …) -> [0, 1, …] -> [n + 0 - n, n + 1 - n, n + 2 - n, …]
```

So, just adding `startIndex` back should do the trick:

```js
/**
 * @template Item
 * @param {Item[]} items
 * @param {number} startIndex
 * @param {number} [endIndex]
 * @returns {Array<{ item: Item; index: number }>}
 */
function slice(items, startIndex, endIndex = items.length) {
    return items.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((item, index) => ({
        item,
        index: index + startIndex,
    }));
}
```

```js
function slice(items, startIndex, endIndex = items.length) {
  return items.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((item, index) => ({
    item,
      index: index + startIndex,
  }));
}

const letters = [ ...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' ];

console.log(slice(letters, 0, 3));
console.log(slice(letters, 3, 6));
console.log(slice(letters, 6, 9));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `array.map()` You can get the all array `value` and `index` !
After this use `.slice()`

Try this code it's help you

```
 const array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge'];
 const slicedArray2 = array.map((v, i) => ({ v, i })).slice(3, 6);
 console.log(slicedArray2, 'slicedArray2');
```

Comment: This approach would've been the best in the general case, but OP rejected it because the original array "is quite large"

Answer (score 0):

I actually like the accepted answer better, but for the record another solution without the `slice`

```js
const data = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge'];

const slice = (items, startIndex, endIndex = items.length) => {
  return items.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
    if (i >= startIndex && i < endIndex )
      acc.push({ v, i })
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(slice(data, 0, 3));
console.log(slice(data, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```